# Phalcon PhP - flash messages not showing

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm having trouble showing flash messages with Phalcon PhP. Here is how I register the service:

```
use Phalcon\Flash\Direct as Flash;
$di->set('flash', function () {
    return new Flash(array(
        'error'   => 'alert alert-danger',
        'success' => 'alert alert-success',
        'notice'  => 'alert alert-info',
        'warning' => 'alert alert-warning'
    ));
});
```

In my controller I add the flash message like this

```
$this->flash->success('The carrier was successfully activated');
```

In my view I try to show like this (volt):

```
{{ flash.output() }}
```

My layout has the `{{ content() }}` tag and I have tried to apply the discussed in [this post](https://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/2631/phalcon-flash-messages-not-displaying) but it doesn't work anyway.

Can you see what I'm missing here? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are using the wrong flash session. Instead of

```
use Phalcon\Flash\Direct as Flash;
```

Use

```
use Phalcon\Flash\Session as Flash;
```

The [documentation](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/flash.html) says:

- `Flash\Direct` will directly outputs the messages passed to the
  flash.
- `Flash\Session` will temporarily store the messages in
  session, then messages can be printed in the next request